# Laravel 5 How to use multi pagination in one page

Tags: laravel-5

Let's say I have a index page which display all the data in database with pagination. I am able to display the correct data and pagination after users perform search, but when I click on the second page, it's not showing the correct data.

```
 public function getNewsletterSearch(Request $request) {
        $keyword = $request->news_search;
        $searchData = DB::table('tbl_contents')
                ->join('tbl_files', function ($join) use($keyword) {
                    $join->on('tbl_contents.unique', '=', 'tbl_files.unique')
                    ->where('tbl_contents.record_type', '=', 'Newsletter')
                    ->where('tbl_contents.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%')
                    ->where('tbl_files.order_id', '=', 1);
                })
                ->orderBy('tbl_contents.id', 'DESC')
                ->select('tbl_contents.*', 'tbl_files.file_name')
                ->paginate(6);

        $searchData->setPageName('page_result');

        return view('newsletter.index')->with(['searchData' => $searchData])->with('search', $keyword);
    }
```

Here is the view:

```
<div class = "col-xs-12">
            <nav aria-label = "Page navigation">
                {{with(new App\Pagination\CustomPresenter($searchData->appends('page_result', Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::get('page_result'))))->render()}}
            </nav>
</div>
```

This is the search function i created. Can I know what is the solution to display the correct data on page 2 from the search result?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete index function which, i had used in my search scenario, take a look and do the necessary modification.

```
public function getNewsletterSearch()
{
    $keyword = request()->get('news_search');

    $searchData = DB::table('tbl_contents')
        ->join('tbl_files', function ($join) use($keyword) {
            $join->on('tbl_contents.unique', '=', 'tbl_files.unique')
            ->where('tbl_contents.record_type', '=', 'Newsletter')
            ->where('tbl_contents.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%')
            ->where('tbl_files.order_id', '=', 1);
        })
        ->orderBy('tbl_contents.id', 'DESC')
        ->select('tbl_contents.*', 'tbl_files.file_name');

    $searchData= $searchData->paginate(6)->appends(request()->query());
    return view('category.index',compact('searchData'));
}
```

in view file

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12"><span class="pull-right">{{$searchData->links()}}</span></div>
```